# How many different ways are there to go from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,3)$?

Tags: coordinate-systems

> There is a cube that is on the $(x, y, z)$ coordinates. How do I construct a systematic way to go from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,3)$? Which subject should I study for this question?

Please help me! I'm trying to solve this question but at the end of my try I found myself counting all the ways one by one.

Comment: Presumably you are only allowed to move one direction with respect to each axis?

Comment: yeah, it can only go one unit at a go in any of the directions of (1,0,0),
(0,1,0), or (0,0,1)

Comment: The first step in solving a problem is always to formulate the problem correctly.

Comment: xyyzxzyzx brings you from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,3)$. It is a sequence of $9$ with $3$ times x, $3$ times y and $3$ times z. How many of these sort or sequences exist? You must choose $3$ out of $9$ to be an x. How many choices? Then you must choose $3$ out of $6$ to be an y. How many choices? Then you are ready. The remainings are z.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have $9$ steps to take in total, and $3$ need to be in the $+x$ direction, $3$ need to be in the $+y$ direction and $3$ need to be in the $+z$ direction, but you can choose to take these steps in any order. Does this suggest anything?

Comment: No actually, what do you mean by any order ? can i choose to take these steps in any order ? isn't  it ordered ? for example if i am on (0,0,0) how can i go (3,0,3) is : firstly i should go (3,0,0) for example after that i can go (3,0,3). am i on the wrong way?

Comment: You are thinking about it in terms of points that you might have to get to before you get to your final destination. You shouldn't think about it that way! Any combination of 3 steps right, 3 steps forward, and the steps up will get you to $(3,3,3)$ from $(0,0,0)$. However the order that you take these steps in defines a unique path from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,3)$, so it suffices to count the number of orderings of steps you can have when there are $9$ in total and there are $3$ sets of triplets of identical steps.

Comment: @user154335 For your new example, you have to go towards $+x$ three times and towards $+z$ three times, in any order. So while you can go $xxxzzz$ for the path $$000>100>200>300>301>302>303,$$
you may also choose to go by $xzzxxz$ for the path
$$000>100>101>102>202>302>303.$$

Comment: ok i got it, then in total; 12 steps to right, 12 steps to up, 12 steps to forward. so i choose 9 ways from 36 different ways ?

Comment: @user154335 not quite, you should look over peterwhy's example above.

Comment: thank you so much ! i found the answer 1680 which is correct i think :)

Comment: Yep, that's what I got for the answer. ${9\choose 3}{6\choose 3}$